# How to slowly move an image inside a div continously to different coordinates

Tags: jquery, html, dhtml

I have an image inside of a `div`.  I would like to use some kind of timer to move the image to various positions inside of the `div`.

Example html:

```
<div id="Container" width="200" height="100"><img src="..."></div>
```

Comment: What "different positions"? The corners?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "move an image to the different positions"? As it is right now the question is worded poorly.

Comment: *"(...) move an image"*, how? Just move, or animated? What type of animation? *"(...) to different positions"*, where? You can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what you've tried.

Comment: More detail on what you have tried and what kind of movement you want would be nice.  Do you want specific positions?  Or random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I whipped something up with jQuery.  What's interesting is that I started by animating `top` and `left` simultaneously, and after some effort and trigonometry, I realized that if you separate the x and y components, the animation of bouncing around in a div becomes a lot easier.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/DcgwR/

Here is a version that can handle multiple elements:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/DcgwR/2/

The key piece of code is:

```
// Parameters
// img: jQuery element (not necessarily img)
// speed: in px/millisecond
// max: maximum distance to travel
// dir: 'left' or 'top'

function bounce(img, speed, max, dir) {
    speed += ((Math.random() * varSpeed) - (varSpeed / 2));
    speed = speed < minSpeed ? minSpeed : (speed > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : speed)
    var time = max / speed;
    var position = img.position();
    var target = (position[dir] < 2) ? max : 0;

    var style = {
        queue: false
    };
    style[dir] = target;
    img.animate(style, {
        duration: time,
        queue: false,
        easing: "linear",
        complete: function() {
            bounce(img, time, max, dir);
        }
    });
}
```

`maxSpeed`, `minSpeed`, `varSpeed` are defined globally (in px/ms), with `varSpeed` being how much the speed varies at each bounce.  I have a separate function `startBounce` which calls `bounce` twice, once for `left` and once for `top`.  Because the animations are not queued, they animate independently.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the choppiness at slower speeds?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px;height:500px">
  <img src="foo.gif" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

Now using jQuery you could do:

```
<script>
  ;(function() {
    var img = $("#container img");
    img.css({ position: "absolute" });
    img.animate({ left: 50, top: 50 });
    img.animate({ left: 100, top: 100 });
    // and so on

    // or if you just want to position it without animation
    img.css({ left: 50, top: 50 });
    // some timeout or similar
    img.css({ left: 100, top: 100 });
    // and so on
  })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<script>
function moveit()
{
  var animatedImg = document.getElementById( "animate" );
  var top = animatedImg.offsetTop;
  var left = animatedImg.offsetLeft;
  top++;
  left++;
  if ( top > 100 )
  {
    top = 0;
  }
  if ( left > 200 )
  {
    left = 0;
  }
  animatedImg.setAttribute( "style", "position: relative; top: " + top + "px; left: " + left + "px;" );
  setTimeout( moveIt, 1000 );
}
</script>
...
<body onload="moveIt()">
<div>
  <img src="imageSource" id="animate" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you don't just want us to write the code for you and want the answer:

You are on the right track, using a timer (lookup: `setTimeout`), on whichyou can change the position (with CSS; lookup properties `position`, `left`, `right` and possibly `margin`, probably `width` and `height`).

If it were me, I'd use jQuery, in which case you should look up `animate`, `.offset()`...